# How to count the teams with no foreign players

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table for the football clubs of a country. The fields are "teamName", "playerName", and "country".

> I'd like to count the clubs that all their players are foreigners

. I tried the following query but I think it's not working since it seems that it counts when we have at least one foreigner but I want it to count if all the players of a team are foreigners!

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT teamName)
FROM teams
WHERE country not like '%England%'
```

Please advise. Thanks!

Comment: can u post the sample table structure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way would be:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT teamName)
FROM teams T1
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
( select * from teams T2 
  WHERE T1.teamName=T2.teamName and T2.country like '%England%')
```

Comment: OP want to count clubs that `all their players are foreigners.` see the question carefully

Comment: Yes, teams where there is no English player. (Edited to remove double-neg.)

Answer (score 0):

Hmm even join seems to need an inner query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM (
  SELECT teamName,
    SUM(country like '%England%') AS Locals
  FROM teams
  GROUP BY teamName
) AS t
WHERE Locals = 0;
```

Seems like there should be a shorter answer though...

Answer (score 0):

**Quick and dirty answer,** and it does only one pass through the data, no subquery. This selects teams that are all foreign. You can play with the `CASE` expression if that is not what you want.

```
SELECT team_name
FROM teams
GROUP BY team_name
HAVING COUNT(country)=
       SUM(CASE country != 'England' WHEN TRUE THEN 1 ELSE 0 END);
```

**Longer answer:** Your schema is not normalized, but should be. You want want table of `teams` and a *second* table of `players`, which includes a foreign key into the team table for that player's current team. This is basic DB normalization. However, replacing the single table in the `FROM` with the join of those two tables, the same `GROUP BY`/`HAVING` trick works.